# Using timed session for login info

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication

Good day,

I have a web site that I'd like to implement login in it with timed session i. e. when I login, after n minutes the session should expired.

BTW, I'm using ASP.NET & C#.

My question is how to accomplish this thin? And is the InProc session helpful in my situation?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Which framework ar you using?

Comment: Sorry hehehe I just edit and added it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the above

```
        <configuration>
         <system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
       </system.web>
       </configuration>
```

Comment: I didn't understand your solution :)

Comment: Can you plz clarify it more